# Setting up Perforce initially

Tags: initialization, perforce

I'd like to use Perforce for source control versioning.  I've been spinning my wheels getting the workspace / depot organized.

The source code to version is in the `c:\home\` directory and contains live web code with several sites and subdirectories, all of which I'd like versioned.

I chose the workspace root as `c:\home\`.  When making a new workspace, I see the files just fine.  Getting them into a Depot is problematic.  Aside from one file in `c:\home`, none of the other folders or files appear.

If the depot is called `HomeDepot`, what are the mapping commands?  What I've tried so far keeps resulting in files not being found.

```
Host: VPS-ABC-12-123 (changed for privacy)
Workspace name: Home
Root: C:\home\
Mapping: //HomeDepot/... //Home/...
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your client spec is fine, so I imagine you just haven't `add`ed the files yet.  You should be able to do:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=Home
cd C:\home
p4 add ...
p4 submit -d "Adding all my files."
```

to get everything into the depot.

If you were starting off completely from scratch, assuming you already have the server up and running somewhere, the entire process of creating a client spec and adding everything to the depot would look like this:

```
p4 set P4PORT=yourserver.com:1666
cd C:\home
p4 client
p4 add ...
p4 submit -d "Adding all my files."
```

- The `p4 set P4PORT=...` is unnecessary if you've set your DNS up so that `perforce:1666` (the default) points to your server.
- The `p4 client` will create a new client using the current value of `P4CLIENT`, which defaults to your local hostname.  You can just save the spec without modifying it; by default a new client uses the working directory as `Root` and maps the entire depot in the `View`.

To set up versioning with a local repository (i.e. you don't need a shared server on a central machine), it's even easier:

```
cd C:\home
p4 init -C1 -n
p4 reconcile
p4 submit -d "Adding all my files."
```

- A local repository is created in `C:\home\.p4root`.
- The `-C1 -n` flags specify that depot filenames are treated as case-insensitive ASCII.  See `p4 help init` for info on other options.
- A stream and workspace are created automatically.
- `P4CONFIG` and `P4IGNORE` files are automatically created, eliminating the need to set `P4PORT` or `P4CLIENT`.

Comment: Thanks, Samwise.  When trying the `add` command, I get `Client 'VPS-ABC-12-123' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.`  That value is in the Host field.

Comment: `p4 set P4CLIENT=Home`.  (If you're going to be sharing this server with other people, note that each client machine needs a unique client spec name.  That's why they default to the local hostname, since those will tend to be unique to the local machine.)

Comment: Underneath the home folder are several websites, one in each folder.  If I create a CLIENT at each of these folders, they'd be unique, and would allow better permissioning, right?

Comment: Permissioning doesn't really have anything to do with client specs, unless you're talking about local permissions for multiple users on this machine -- in which case yeah, you probably want each local user to have their own Perforce username and their own client that maps the local folder(s) they have permission to.  Permissions on the Perforce side are managed within the depot namespace (not the client namespace) by `p4 protect`.

Comment: If you do have multiple client specs and/or users on one machine, you should use `P4CONFIG` to manage those configurations so that they swap automatically according to the working directory; much easier than having to remember to `p4 set` the right thing each time you switch workspaces.

Comment: Then yeah, just one workspace mapping the root (which is the default for a new client spec anyway) makes perfect sense, and permissions aren't an issue at all if there's only one user.

Comment: My prior attempts in P4V are interfering with the add command.  When I tried to submit the changelist in P4V, the system spins and nothing gets added.  When using DOS, Says they are already set for add.  The DOS CLIENT command did not help in that P4V GUI submit, and I'm concerned if I submit at DOS, they won't be visible in P4V due to the current error.

How I can start all over?
Are you open to remoting in?

Comment: If they're already open for add, just `p4 submit`.  Once you submit the files, you should be able to refresh P4V and see them in the depot.  If there's some kind of server error preventing the submit from succeeding, you might get a more useful error message at the command line.  (Could it be your server is out of disk space?  Did you set up a trigger on the server that might be blocking the submit?)

Comment: Thanks again, Samwise. There are no triggers. We have 60+ Gb of disk space.

I reverted all the P4V because it was stuck somehow.

When I try syncing to head from //HomeDepot, I get this:
1 warning reported
//HomeDepot/...#head - no such file(s).

I did the two DOS commands, and they did succeed. I cannot see those additions in P4V.  Now I'm attempting to do the add command from DOS, and the system is spinning indefinitely.

My sincerest apologies for this difficulty.

Comment: I suggest posting on http://forums.perforce.com so we can do some actual debugging.  You said you did "the two commands" (the `add` and `submit`?) and they worked, but now the add command is "spinning"...?  Why did you redo the "add"?  Very tough to have a useful conversation in these tiny comment boxes.

Comment: Thankj you, Samwise, for your assistance.  The \home\ folder has 147K files in it, which is why the `add` command was spinning.  It took hours to complete.  When I `submit`, many of the files were related to an installation of Eclipse and were locked.  Each line took many seconds before resulting in a lock error so I used Ctrl^C to abort.

I don't see the //stream files in P4V.  I'd like to trim out the files that are not needed.

Comment: If you aborted the submit, nothing got submitted.  `revert` the files you don't need, or better yet, revert everything (`p4 revert ...`), fix your client/stream view to exclude the unneeded files (that's `p4 stream` if you're using a stream, or `p4 client` if not), and then start over with `p4 add ...` (it'll ignore all the files you excluded from your view).

Comment: The revert process is taking place.  Which option (stream or client) can I use in P4V?

Comment: This is still an on-going hardship, Samwise.  I don't see in P4V what I'm doing in DOS.  I plan to uninstall and reinstall everything to lose the stream, lose the clients and start over with the simple commands above.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241222/discussion-between-brentshaub-and-samwise